Unexpected WebAuthn / passkey prompt
Safari prompted me to authenticate to ioc.exchange today, when I had no Safari tabs or windows with ioc.exchange open. I do have an ioc.exchange account that I use only rarely. I do not have ioc.exchange set up in Internet Accounts, and I was in Safari when the popup surfaced.
Edit: Someone may be poking around ... I just got an unsolicited push MFA request from Microsoft Authenticator. Probably just a coincidence but wanted to mention it.
Edit 2: Not answer but I spoke with someone involved in the development of FIDO2 specs who assured me the dialog box could only pop up if "... something made a call from that origin in an app or browser." What would have made a call from ioc.exchange to my browser is beyond me.
Are there any non-sketchy reasons this might happen? As far as I know webauthn/passkeys doesn't support a push authentication model (someone somewhere else trying to log in as me resulting in a prompt on my machine).


Interesting. Do you have ioc configured (disabled or enabled) in system settings, internet accounts? What is the context of that dialog window. Is it floating over a black desktop or are other apps running or in the foreground? I presume you’re in safari on some other site based on the image, but would like to be sure before trying to answer.

I don't have ioc in internet accounts. I was in Safari when the dialog popped up. I don't remember which website I was on but it was not ioc.exchange ot any other Mastodon server.
